# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 8518

Tags: laravel-5, salesforce, apex

Im sending request from salesforce to laravel then laravel return the result and display them on visual force page

Error Detail

[image]

Apex Method

```
 public List<SelectOption> getItems()
    {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setEndpoint('http://clozer.3spire.net/public/goclozer/country');
        req.setMethod('GET');

        req.setCompressed(false);
        req.setBody('key1=value1&key2=value2');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');  

         try {
            res = http.send(req);                   
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            system.debug('Callout error: '+ e);         
        }                

        getAllCountry = (Map<String, String>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),Map<String, String>.class);

        List<SelectOption> option = new List<SelectOption>();

        option.add(new SelectOption('0','--None--'));        
        for(String c : getAllCountry.values())
        {
            option.add(new SelectOption(c,c));
        }

        return option;
    }
```

Expected Result

```
{"0":"Aruba","1":"Antigua and Barbuda","2":"United Arab Emirates","3":"Afghanistan","4":"Algeria","5":"Azerbaijan","6":"Albania","7":"Armenia","8":"Andorra","9":"Angola","10":"American Samoa","11":"Argentina","12":"Australia","13":"Ashmore and Cartier Islands"}
```

Laravel 5 Route

```
Route::get('/goclozer/country','GoClozerController@getCountry');
```

Laravel 5 Method

```
public function getCountry()
    {
        $country = \App\Country::all();
        $names = array();

        foreach($country as $c)
        {
            $names[] = $c->name;
        }
        echo json_encode($names,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    }
```

How can i get ride of this error
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

MethodNotAllowedHttpException means that you're using wrong HTTP verb ( Get, Post, Put, Delete ...). You've route defined for GET, but you may be posting data

The modification (as I assume you just want to retrieve the country names only) can be achieved by

```
    $countries = Country::all(['name']);
```

this will only retrieve the names of the countries from the table, you can add more fields if you want to.

Controller gets a request, returns a response. You're not returning any response. just echoing the result. You can do the following,

```
    return $countries;
```

This will simply return the JSON with country names.

You don't have to put an explicit slash at the front of route declaration. you can even write like the following and that will work too.

```
    Route::get('goclozer/country','GoClozerController@getCountry');
```